# StackOverflowError when running JUnit tests in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am having trouble running JUnit tests on the Koans from [neo4j-tutorial](https://github.com/jimwebber/neo4j-tutorial)
I am using  Intellij of the following version on Windows 7:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 Build #IC-145.1617, built on June 3, 2016 JRE:
>   1.8.0_92-b14 amd64 JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

I have generated the eclipse stuff with `ant generate.eclipse.project` as written in the README. However when I try to run a Koan I am faced with a `StackOverflowErrror`

This is a part of the stack trace:

```
Information:Using javac 1.7.0_80 to compile java sources
 ...
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.AttrContext.dup(AttrContext.java:92)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1417)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1321)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:2247)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1677)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:449)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1521)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'neo4j-tutorial'
Information:2016/06/23 16:57 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 32 warnings in 1s 379ms
Error:java: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I have set the VM option of this test as the following:

```
-ea
-Xss1m
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Adding -Xss4m to the build process VM options should help

Build, Execution, Deployment - > Compiler -> Goto Property "Shared Build Process VM Option" and set it  -Xss4M