# StackOverflowError when running tests with coverage in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, test-coverage

I've been writting some tests in my project and when running the tests by command line with `./gradlew test` or from Android Studio by clicling "Run tests in java" all the tests are executed successfully. But when I try to run all the tests with covergage I get the following error and there a few tests that are not executed:

```
---- IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner ---- 
sampling ...
include patterns:
exclude patterns:
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
Class transformation time: 0.823138756s for 3466 classes or 2.3748954298903635E-4s per class
Exception in thread "Thread-2" 
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-2"
[2021.06.28 16:28:50] (Coverage): Unexpected error: java.lang.StackOverflowError
Exception in thread "Thread-0" 
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-0"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know how can I get more information about whay is the cause, but I guess that if when executing them normally there's no problem, there's no problem in the tests.

I have revised [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985783/stackoverflowerror-when-running-junit-tests-in-intellij), but there's no such option. Also the IDE suggested to increment the heap by modifying the file studio.vmoptions located in `/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/studio.vmoptions` (for Mac) but I have the same problem when increasing it from -Xmx1024m to -Xmx2048m or more.

Edit: When running the tests with coverage individually they are executed successfully.